# Android Studio не импортирует AppCompatActivity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-app-compat-activity

Android Studio перестал видеть импорт AppCompatActivity (прикрепил скрин) и вообще весь пакет androidx вроде после того как я зашел в этот пакет посмотреть что расширяет один класс, вот создал новый проект а проблема не ушла, на каком то сайте предлагали в Project Structure добавить appcompat.v7 добавил и ничего не поменялось (прикрепил скрин), Event log тоже прикрепил

вот Gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 32
    buildToolsVersion "32.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.e.kitkat_44"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

[image: MainActivity]
[image: Project Structure]
[image: Event Log]

Comment: Обновите IDE, и Gradle

Comment: С утра все работало

Comment: Я вас не спрашивал, работало с утра или нет. А написал что сделать надо

Comment: Так что поменялось с утра? Gradle всегда можно обновить.

Comment: Разобрался, как обычно проблема была не там где искал, в брандмауэре было отключено правило для Java Binary platform включил и все заработало